# Dynamic Linq access items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dynamic LINQ query like below.

```
 var results=DataTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
                .Select(selectObjStr)
                .GroupBy("new (Country,City)", "it")
                .Select("new (Key.Country as Country, Key.City as City)");
```

which results in

```
[0] = {Country=India, City=Bangalore}

[1] = {Country=India, City=Mangalore}

[2] = {Country=USA, City=LA}
```

How can i access the each key items from the result? I have tried like

```
foreach(var row in results)
{
  //but row does not have key column Country or city
}
```

Please help me

Comment: How you see results you claim? Also what is in quick watch (or local) window, when you are in foreach loop? ( what is row?)

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
for(int i =0; i < results.Count();i++)
{
   results[i].Country;
}
```

try it, but not sure

Comment: But I cannot perform indexing in this case.